# Django query: Users can ask many questions and bookmark many questions. How to count total bookmarks for all of a single user's questions asked?

Tags: django, django-models

A user can ask many questions.

```
How many = User.question_set.all().count()
```

A question can be bookmarked by many users (once per user).

```
How many = Question.bookmark_set.all().count()
```

How many users have bookmarked the all questions asked by a single user?

```
How many = ???
```

My models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField()

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bookmark_count = User.objects.filter(bookmark__question__user=user).count()
unique_users = User.objects.filter(bookmark__question__user=user).distinct().count()
```

You may have to change `user` in `bookmark__question__user` to match your question models owner.